# Storing and Retrieving OpenStruct from Database?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm currently trying to find the best way to store and retrieve some nested data from a database in Rails 3. I make a call to an API and it returns back and outputs in an OpenStruct format. Some of the data is one level deep and I am parsing this and storing only the value in the database. No problems there. However, some of the items being returned have 100s of sub items and I really don't want to have to make a mess of my tables. So what I've done so far is just save everything second level or deeper directly into the database.

Just to give you an example, let's say I'm getting info on a car which I am storing to my cars database. So basically make and model are getting saved out a strings, but let's say a field for specs which has all of the cars specs nested within it in OpenStruct. So rather than going spec1 = car.specs.spec1, spec 2= car.specs.spec2 ... specs100 = car.specs.spec100, etc I'm doing specs = car.specs and saving that to the database. (Very loose example just to give a general idea.)

My issue is retrieving that data. Traversing the data doesn't seem to work anymore.

If I try and output some of the nested info I get "undefined method".

If I output the entire field I get something like: "Car Spec1: --- !ruby/object:OpenStruct table: :spec2: Something Here :spec3: Something Here :spec4: Something Here :spec5: !ruby/object:OpenStruct table: ... etc etc"

I am rather new to Rails as well as the OpenStruct format so I'd appreciate any help in trying to retrieve the data. Or perhaps a better way of saving the data in the first place. What am I missing?

db/schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120401042641) do

  create_table "characters", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "realm"
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "level"
    t.integer  "race"
    t.integer  "class_id"
    t.integer  "gender"
    t.text     "guild"
    t.text     "talents"
    t.text     "items"
  end

  add_index "characters", ["user_id"], :name => "index_characters_on_user_id"

end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "save directly into the database" what are the column types of the database. what declarations have you made in your active record model against those records. marking a field as serializable against a text column is often good enough but I've never Tried openstruct, just hashes.

Comment: Show us the relevant parts of your model code and your db/schema.db.

Comment: I added a copy of the relevant table from my db/schema.rb. So basically the two specific columns that I am having problems with would be the talents and items columns. All of the other items return back a string or integer that I am storing directly to the DB. However talents and items have a lot of subsets of data, which in return have their own subsets of data. I'd like to be able to save that data grouped and then still be able to retrieve it and then parse out specific items that I need.

Comment: I haven't made any special declarations on the data. I merely pull it out and then am trying to access it via the dot syntax method used to traverse OpenStruct. However, if you don't know how to do it with ostruct I'd be open to hearing more about your method using hashes. I'm open to alternatives.

Comment: And where is your model declaration. You need to declare those fields as serializable probably but you don't include all information so I am just guessing.

Comment: bradgonesurfing I appreciate you trying to help. I was able to find my answer shortly after my last two comments. Your first comment actually pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After bradgonesurfing's first comment I decided to try serialize with OpenStruct. Works just like with hashes for the most part.

`serialize :field` (in my model)

Then you can retrieve the data by calling `field.something.something` etc.